# flyway-maven-plugin: how to execute multiple database configurations together?

Tags: java, maven, flyway

I am integrating Flyway in to an existing legacy project, which consists of multiple databases for the same application. The project uses Maven and I want to use the maven-flyway-plugin to integrate with Flyway.

My working configuration so far looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>db1</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>db2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>db2</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                ...
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

With this I can migrate each database separately like this:

```
mvn flyway:migrate@db1 flyway:migrate@db2 flyway:migrate@db3
```

Unfortunately this is not very user friendly. I want to be able to simply execute `mvn flyway:migrate` and execute all three migration configurations.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

maven works this way. You can either extends flyway plugin with your needs or you can migrate to gradle which can gather multiple 'job'

Eric